# unable to access environment variables from docker compose env file

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a problem with reading the .env variables from a docker-compose.yml file (version -3.7), here first I explain my folder and sample code structure

My folder structure

**my_app**

- src

  - config.py
  - app.py
  - requirements.txt
  - other files
- Dockerfile
- docker-compose.yml
- .env

**.env file**

This is my sample .env file

```
    ENVIRONMENT_NAME=DEV
    DATABASE_NAME=testing
```

**docker-compose.yml file**

This is my sample docker-compose.yml file (version: 3.7)

```
    version: "3.7"
    services:
        my_app_test:
            env_file: ./.env
            image: my-app-test
            build:
                context: ./src
                dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

**Dockerfile**

This is my sample Dockerfile

```
    FROM python:3.7-alpine
    
    # Install required packages
    RUN apk add --update --no-cache \
        build-base \
        postgresql-dev \
        linux-headers \
        pcre-dev \
        py-pip \
        bash \
        curl \
        openssl \
        nginx \
        libressl-dev \
        musl-dev \
        libffi-dev \
        rsyslog \
        && pip install Cython
    
    # Create container's working directory
    RUN mkdir -p /MyApp
    # Copy all source files to the container's working directory
    COPY ./ /MyApp
    # Install all python dependency libs
    RUN pip install -r /MyApp/requirements.txt
    
    WORKDIR /MyApp
    ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
```

**src/config.py**

Here in the config file, I am reading all the environment variables

```
    import os
    from pathlib import Path    
    from dotenv import load_dotenv
    
    ENV_PATH = Path('.env')
    load_dotenv(dotenv_path=ENV_PATH)
    
    ENVIRONMENT_NAME = os.getenv('ENVIRONMENT_NAME')
    DATABASE_NAME = os.getenv("DATABASE_NAME")
```

**src/app.py**

Here in the app.py file, I am getting the variables from config.py and use that in my project. When I run this file after building a docker image, it is not working as expected. All the env variables are read as None

```
    import config
    import os
    
    print(config.ENVIRONMENT_NAME)
    print(config.DATABASE_NAME)
    
    # Access all environment variables
    print('\n')
    print(os.environ)
```

I am trying to access env sets from the docker-compose file and not from Dockerfile.

Docker build is working fine, After that when I try to run the docker image (***sudo docker run my-app-test app.py***) it does not print the environment variables as I expected. **The output of the current code is**,

```
None 

None 

environ({'PATH': '/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin', 'HOSTNAME': '6cfc0c912772', 'LANG': 'C.UTF-8', 'GPG_KEY': '0D96DF4D4110E5C43FBFB17F2D347EA6AA65421D', 'PYTHON_VERSION': '3.7.5', 'PYTHON_PIP_VERSION': '19.3.1', 'PYTHON_GET_PIP_URL': 'https://github.com/pypa/get-pip/raw/ffe826207a010164265d9cc807978e3604d18ca0/get-pip.py', 'PYTHON_GET_PIP_SHA256': 'b86f36cc4345ae87bfd4f10ef6b2dbfa7a872fbff70608a1e43944d283fd0eee', 'HOME': '/root'})
```

Requirements am using is,

1. python=3.7
2. python-dotenv==0.12.0

I want to fix this env reading issue. I am not sure where the problem is, @anyone pls help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting ENV at build time, so docker-compose will able to read `env file` as you set configuration in the compose file, but `docker run` will not read the `env` as you need to specify `env file`

You need to specify `env-file` in docker run command

```
docker run --env-file .env my-app-test app.py
```

or to just check ENV

```
docker run --env-file .env --entrypoint printenv my-app-test
```

or run the stack

```
docker-compose up
```

Comment: @CHIDAMBARANATHANM it should work, let me know if there is still probem

Answer (score 0):

`docker run` will not find the `env` file because the env file is specified in the `docker-compose.yml` file.

Try running your container like this instead:

```
docker-compose run my_app_test app.py
```

Comment: Above comment gives this error, **ERROR: No such service: my-app-test** @Peaceful James

Comment: I have edited my answer. It has to be the service name in your docker-compose file. Use underscores instead of hyphens.